# Android Instant app: Failed to notify the platform of the successful install

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, android-app-bundle

I have an instant-enabled app, which I have uploaded onto the Google Play Internal test track.

When I share this link to my testers, and they click 'Try Now' for the first time, it starts "installing" as you would expect, and the splash screen loads, but then seems to crash, and take me back to the play store listing page. When you click `Try Now` again, it works fine (as the instant app is on the device). The reason seems to be this:

```
2019-10-18 15:57:39.257 10058-10058/? E/Finsky:instant_app_inst: [2] com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.EphemeralInstallerActivity.t(20): Failed to notify the platform of the successful install.
    android.content.IntentSender$SendIntentException
        at android.content.IntentSender.sendIntent(IntentSender.java:198)
        at android.content.IntentSender.sendIntent(IntentSender.java:155)
        at njq.a(PG:3)
        at com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.EphemeralInstallerActivity.t(PG:15)
        at com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.EphemeralInstallerActivity.k(Unknown Source:0)
        at agyb.X(Unknown Source:20)
        at mzz.a(Unknown Source:6)
        at agij.a(Unknown Source:14)
        at ap.b(PG:4)
        at ap.a(PG:16)
        at ap.a(PG:20)
        at agik.a(PG:3)
        at al.run(PG:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Is this something that will only occur in the internal test track? or has anyone else experienced this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're still bumping into this issue, please report it to Google's instant apps tracker @ https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787